# how can I set file name prefix while copying the snowflake data via copy into statement for the partitioned data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to unload the snowflake data into ADLSGen2 and also performing the partition of the data while copying.

By default the files are created in a data lake specified path with names data_0_0_1*, I would like to change the file names to a different prefix. Is it supported/possible?. Much appreciated your inputs.
Example snowflake statement which I am using is

```
copy into @my-storage/SF/TEST/ from(
select * from "DEMODB"."PRS"."TEST_TABLE") 
partition by'date=' || to_varchar(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') )
FILE_FORMAT = ( FORMAT_NAME = 'sf_test_parquet_format' )
header = true,
max_file_size = 32000000
OVERWRITE = FALSE;
```

Comment: You can specify a filename prefix on your copy command like **copy into @my-storage/SF/TEST/my_file**, see our docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#required-parameters). See especially this point: **The optional path parameter specifies a folder and filename prefix for the file(s) containing unloaded data. If a filename prefix is not included in path, the filenames for the generated data files are prefixed with data_.**

Comment: Thank you for the reply,the file names prefix is still not clear ,

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the file names prefix is not created as expected based on documentation, for example,  `@my-storage/SF/TEST//././part ...partition by year .. `, in this scenario it is creating a subfolder called part in the year folder and within that data_* file is created. I am looking for the file name to part_0_0_01.parquet...etc. When the partition is not added the filename-prefix is taken as part_...as expected. Do I miss something here?

Comment: As far as I can see I believe when you use PARTITION BY the filename prefix is hardcoded to start with **data_**